# Need to simplify SQL query (Enter date at four locations)

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a query which calculates the average of several sums over multiple tables. This needs to be run every week and how the code is made currently I need to change 4 dates in the query every time. I'm thinking this can be done more efficiently but i'm unsure how.

```sql
Select ROUND(

(Select sum (calls)
            FROM (SELECT sum(ski.ANSTIME) AS calls
            FROM SYNONYMS syn 
            JOIN SKILL ski on (syn.value = ski.split) 
            WHERE syn.ITEM_TYPE = 'split'  
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(ski.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) >= '17-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(ski.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) <= '24-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week

            UNION ALL

            SELECT sum(vdn.ANSTIME) AS calls
            FROM SYNONYMS syn 
            JOIN VDN vdn on (syn.value = vdn.vdn) 
            WHERE syn.ITEM_TYPE = 'vdn'
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(vdn.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) >= '17-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(vdn.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) <= '24-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW')) -- Date to be altered every week 

/ -- devided by

            (SELECT sum (calltime)
            FROM        (SELECT sum(ski.acdcalls) AS calltime
            FROM SYNONYMS syn 
            JOIN SKILL ski on (syn.value = ski.split) 
            WHERE syn.ITEM_TYPE = 'split' 
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(ski.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) >= '17-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(ski.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) <= '24-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week

            UNION ALL

            SELECT sum(vdn.acdcalls) AS calltime
            FROM SYNONYMS syn 
            JOIN VDN vdn on (syn.value = vdn.vdn) 
            WHERE syn.ITEM_TYPE = 'vdn'
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(vdn.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw'
                FROM dual) >= '17-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW' -- Date to be altered every week
            AND (SELECT (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +numtodsinterval(vdn.starttime_utc, 'SECOND'))
                at time zone 'Europe/Warsaw' 
                FROM dual) <= '24-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW')) -- Date to be altered every week

,0) AS average
FROM dual
```

Comment: Why not convert it into a procedure with two parameters, so that you just change the parameters each time?

Comment: Is synoyms.item_type unique? Or could there be multiple synonyms.value values for each synonyms.item_type?

Comment: syn.item_type is not unique, there are a lot of different syn.value values per syn.item_type

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to generate some weekly summary so instead of entering date you can try to use `trunc(sysdate)` for second date and `trunc(sysdate - 7)` for first.

Second possibility is to create temporary table (or just `with` statement) which will hold single date and join that to your query. Instead `<= '24-07-17 00:00:00 EUROPE/WARSAW'` you will have `<= temp_date` where `temp_date` comes from CTE.

Comment: The tables have the calls start time stored as a unix timecode. Every week I need an average of all calls received in the previous week (week 29 in the example). So sysdate won't work unless I use sysdate to find out the start and end of the previous week. Using a stored procedure might work, but haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: But you can insert your unix time or even week start based on that into temp table and then join to table.

Comment: For start of week try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515514/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-week-in-oracle