# Oracle SQL query to list weeks between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I have one requirement

START_DATE : 03/01/2018
END_DATE : 31/01/2018

I need a query which will list all the weeks starting date and end date between these two dates like this

```
StartWeek   EndWeek
03/01/2018  04/01/2018
07/01/2018  11/01/2018
14/01/2018  18/01/2018
21/01/2018  25/01/2018
28/01/2018  31/01/2018
```

Here working days are from Sunday to thursday. Week starts from sunday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the start and end dates of all weeks between two dates in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071312/how-to-get-the-start-and-end-dates-of-all-weeks-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)

Comment: @AkshayTilekar - the question is tagged `[oracle]` so it is highly unlikely that a SQL Server answer will help: the two products have very different approaches to manipulating dates. Don't fall into the trap of thinking `[sql]` tag means MS SQL Server: it doesn't, it just means this is a question about writing SQL statements.

Comment: @APC He will need to change the Query accordingly, that's what i mean.

Comment: @AkshayTilekar - that's not what "possible duplicate" means.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515514/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-week-in-oracle. I think you have there all you need.

Comment: What do you mean by week starting date? Maybe you mix it with "working day". For example in Europe the weeks starts on Monday, in America the weeks starts on Sunday. However, in both regions the first working day is Monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE week_pkg
AS
    TYPE week_rec IS RECORD (start_week DATE, end_week DATE);
    TYPE week_tab IS TABLE OF week_rec;
    FUNCTION get_weeks (p_start_date DATE, p_end_date DATE) RETURN week_tab PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY week_pkg
AS
    FUNCTION get_weeks (p_start_date DATE, p_end_date DATE) RETURN week_tab PIPELINED
    IS
        v_date DATE;
        v_week_rec week_rec;
    BEGIN
        v_date := p_start_date - 7;

        LOOP
             v_week_rec.start_week := NEXT_DAY(v_date, 'SUNDAY');
             IF v_week_rec.start_week < p_start_date THEN
                 v_week_rec.start_week:= p_start_date;
             END IF;

             v_week_rec.end_week := NEXT_DAY(v_date, 'THURSDAY');


             IF v_week_rec.end_week >= p_end_date THEN
                 v_week_rec.end_week := p_end_date;
                 PIPE ROW (v_week_rec);
                 EXIT;
             ELSIF v_week_rec.end_week <= p_start_date THEN
                 v_week_rec.end_week := NEXT_DAY(v_week_rec.start_week, 'THURSDAY');
             END IF;

             v_date := v_week_rec.end_week;

             PIPE ROW (v_week_rec);
         END LOOP;
    END;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM table(week_pkg.get_weeks(to_date('03-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), to_date('31-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')));
```

Output:

```
START_WEEK END_WEEK
---------- ---------
03-JAN-18  04-JAN-18
07-JAN-18  11-JAN-18
14-JAN-18  18-JAN-18
21-JAN-18  25-JAN-18
28-JAN-18  31-JAN-18
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You could use this SQL.

```
WITH t (START_DATE, END_DATE)
     AS (SELECT TO_DATE ('03/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
                TO_DATE ('31/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           FROM DUAL)
    SELECT DISTINCT
           CASE
              WHEN LEVEL = 1
              THEN
                 START_DATE
              ELSE
                 CASE
                    WHEN TRUNC (START_DATE + LEVEL + 7, 'DAY') > END_DATE
                    THEN
                       TRUNC (START_DATE + LEVEL, 'DAY')
                    ELSE
                       TRUNC (START_DATE + LEVEL + 7, 'DAY')
                 END
           END
              START_DATE,
           CASE
              WHEN NEXT_DAY (
                      CASE
                         WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN START_DATE
                         ELSE TRUNC (START_DATE + LEVEL + 7, 'DAY')
                      END,
                      'THURSDAY') > END_DATE
              THEN
                 END_DATE
              ELSE
                 NEXT_DAY (
                    CASE
                       WHEN LEVEL = 1
                       THEN
                          CASE
                             WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (START_DATE, 'DAY')) = 'THURSDAY'
                             THEN
                                START_DATE - 7
                             ELSE
                                START_DATE
                          END
                       ELSE
                          TRUNC (START_DATE + LEVEL + 7, 'DAY')
                    END,
                    'THURSDAY')
           END
              END_DATE
      FROM DUAL CROSS JOIN t
CONNECT BY LEVEL < END_DATE - START_DATE;
```

Comment: Does this work when `2018-01-03` is a Wednesday? 7 days later the start date would be another Wednesday rather than a Sunday at the start of the OP's working week.

Comment: @MT0 : I feel this has ended up being uglier than i imagined. Lost quite a lot of my time to get this to work !

Comment: I added a link to my answer with to an [Oracle Live SQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f3o7fhodasudilb7gs3jnump2) which has my answer but also has a second statement using a hierarchical query that is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH input_dates ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-03', DATE '2018-01-31'
  FROM   DUAL
),
valid_start_date ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN start_date - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' )
                IN (
                  0, -- Monday
                  1, -- Tuesday
                  2, -- Wednesday
                  3, -- Thursday
                  6  -- Sunday
                )
         THEN start_date
         ELSE NEXT_DAY( start_date, 'SUNDAY' )
         END,
         end_date
  FROM   input_dates
),
dates ( start_week, end_week, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT start_date,
         LEAST( NEXT_DAY( start_date, 'THURSDAY' ), end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   valid_start_date
  WHERE  start_date <= end_date
UNION ALL
  SELECT NEXT_DAY( start_week, 'SUNDAY' ),
         LEAST( end_week + INTERVAL '7' DAY, end_date ),
         end_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  NEXT_DAY( start_week, 'SUNDAY' ) <= end_date
)
SELECT start_week, end_week
FROM   dates;
```

[Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f3o7fhodasudilb7gs3jnump2)

Output:

```
START_DATE END_DATE
---------- ----------
2018-01-03 2018-01-04
2018-01-07 2018-01-11
2018-01-14 2018-01-18
2018-01-21 2018-01-25
2018-01-28 2018-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that: Oracle 11 and higher (maybe Oracle 9 and 10 too...)

If Your week begins with Sunday, maybe You should subtract 1 day in the inner sql. 
("select trunc(dt, 'IW')-1 as beg_period" for week beginning with Sunday -instead of "select trunc(dt, 'IW') as beg_period" for week beginning with Monday)

```
with periods as
(
    select greatest(to_date(&date_from, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), beg_period) beg_period -- date_from or first day of week
           , least(to_date(&date_to, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), lead(beg_period) over (order by beg_period)-1 )  end_period -- date_to or last day of week (and =NULL if week begins AFTER date_to)
    from 
    (select trunc(dt, 'IW')-1 as beg_period -- calc the beginning of week for every day generated, taking week beginning in Sunday ("-1")
     from 
        (-- generate all the days between &date_from and FIRST DAY OF NEXT WEEK JUST AFTER &date_to (including)
         select to_date(&date_from, 'dd.mm.yyyy') + (level-1) as dt 
         from dual 
         connect by level <= (trunc(to_date(&date_to, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'IW') + 7 -- also calc the first day of next week just AFTER date_to; it needed 
                                                                               -- for lead(...) in further (just to calc end-of-week for date_to, by lead(...))
                               - to_date(&date_from, 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
                               + 1
                             )   
        )                              
     group by trunc(dt, 'IW') -- take only 1 beg_period for every week (may use "group by", or "distinct")
   )
)     
select beg_period
  , end_period - case to_char(end_period, 'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''numeric date language''') when '7' then 2 when '6' then 1 else 0 end
   as end_period -- correction for weekend (Friday and Saturday) for week beginning in Sunday
from periods 
where end_period is not null -- exclude next week just after date_to (which has end_period=NULL)
order by 1
;
```

See the last "case": it depends on NLS. In my expression, I mean Saturday='7' and Friday='6' (I guess it's correct if week begins with Sunday).

Answer (score 0):

> Elegant solution

```
  SELECT DISTINCT  TO_CHAR(z.START_DATE,'MMRRRR') MM  
            ,TO_CHAR(z.START_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR') START_DATE 
            ,TO_CHAR(z.END_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR') END_DATE
    FROM  (WITH C_RANGE AS   
    (SELECT TRUNC(:STARTDATE) + LEVEL - 1 FECHA_INI
                ,ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(:STARTDATE),LEVEL) - 1 FECHA_FIN
        FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TRUNC(:ENDDATE) - TRUNC(:STARTDATE)))
    SELECT DISTINCT
               (CASE WHEN L.FECHA_INI = TRUNC(:STARTDATE) THEN TRUNC(:STARTDATE) ELSE ADD_MONTHS(L.FECHA_FIN,-1) +1 END) START_DATE
              ,(CASE WHEN L.FECHA_FIN +1 >= TRUNC(:ENDDATE)  THEN  TRUNC(:ENDDATE) ELSE L.FECHA_FIN  END)  END_DATE  
      FROM  C_RANGE L
     WHERE ADD_MONTHS(L.FECHA_FIN,-1) <= TRUNC(:ENDDATE)
         AND  TRUNC(:ENDDATE) >= TRUNC(:STARTDATE)) z
   ORDER BY MM ASC ;
```